# geometry nodes: prevent instances from overlapping

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry, instances

I'm a beginner blender user, I'm trying to model this material:

[image]

which gets volume after absorbing water:

[image]

I started modeling a pile using nodes, but the resulted instances are overlapping, how to proceed to get them separated particles? (a grip/bunch of individual separated grains as in the first image)

[image]

[image]

2- I'll be glad if someone give me hint about how to model the hydrated material as in second picture (modeling and material transparent)

sorry, i can't find how to join the .blend file.

thank you All.

Comment: To upload a blend use https://blend-exchange.com ... Image 1: Add "Realize Instances" node, "Apply" modifier, in edit mode search "Separate by Loose Parts", search Origin to Geometry, use Rigid Body Physics. Image 2: use what you have with Glass material and Noise texture for Roughness should be looking similar ... I just hope you don't want an animation :)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.. It won't help with the intersecting but what you could do is convert them into volumes and back into a mesh in geometry nodes, which kinda smoothes out the intersections and makes it look like they clump together.

If you really need them to not intersect, [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QA13LPCZ3dM) might be helpful:

Comment: Thanks for the link great solution :) It is a shame you provided just a link that is not permanent (usually not allowed as prime source of knowledge here) ... would be awesome if you take a time to mention key points (text or image) here. Thank you keep this site useful.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for letting me know, I'm a newby on this platform, so I didn't know. Will do when I have time :)

Comment: To clarify, there's nothing *wrong* with posting a link to *supplement* your answer. But you should post the main concept from that link in the answer so people don't need to rely on the link alone. Ask yourself: if this link ever breaks, will my answer still have value? Because links can break. (While major sites likes YouTube are unlikely to disappear anytime soon, individual channels or videos can.) And we're trying to create a repository of knowledge here that will be resilient enough to withstand link rot over time.

Comment: Video using mesh to volume and volume to mesh https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDP1d0s1ges